# Issues when using generator-jhipster-react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster

Is generator-jhipster-react  generator still being worked on? I tried to create a project and got stuck on `Would you like to enable this option? (Y/n)` and Y or n doesnt make any difference since there are no package.json or bower json file. I saw that there have been no commits the last 3 months.

Comment: Surely leaving an issue on the github would present faster results than posting here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `generator-jhipster-react` is currently (as of May 9th 2016) being worked on and is not ready for usage.

Comment: I assume this is dead in the water? would be good if someone else picked it up. Angular 4 is a big task to learn now...

Comment: Work is happening. See [this issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6044) and [this branch.](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/jh-react)